# Change the color of the link which is generated by \htmladdnormallink

Tags: hyperref, color, links

I try to write a book, and I'm beginner with some functions in LaTeX. I already have looked for this question even I looked in hyperref manual and I have not found anything about how to change the color of a link which is generated by the function `\htmladdnormallink`, because its default color is pink "when I specify" `colorlinks`. I want a different color. What could be used to solve this problem?

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{book}

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\htmladdnormallink {example}{https://www.itisnotexistitisanexample.com}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `book` class does not have a `reqno` option, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

`\htmladdnormallink` is a wrapper for `\href`, which uses the colour set with the `urlcolor` option. If the colour should be changed, then set `urlcolor=...` to the desired value.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage[colorlinks,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\htmladdnormallink {example}{https://www.itisnotexistitisanexample.com}
\end{document}
```

[image]